# When to use ĉi tiu vs tiu ĉi?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between *tiu ĉi* and *ĉi tiu*? Since both mean **this**, in what situations should one be used over the other? The following sentence comes from Duolingo and is an example of the former.

> Tiu ĉi rado funkcias bone.
>
> *This wheel works well.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just preference. This for example applies to *tie ĉi* and *ĉi tie* as well.

Answer (score 2):

The other day I saw someone write *tiu ĉi tie*. Obviously, the above doesn't have a clear meaning. I would suggest using a more external approach:

*Ĉi tiu tie* or *tiu tie ĉi*

Comment: Can you provide more context of this use, or at least the whole corresponding sentence?